# Type declaration for dynamically created properties (setattr)

Tags: python, python-typing

I am writing a class which dynamically sets its attributes according to a `dict` passed to the constructor:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, track_data:dict[Any,Any]) -> None:
        valid_attributes = [member.value for member in fields]
            
        for field,value in track_data.items():
            if field not in valid_attributes:
                raise Exception(f"{field} is not a valid field")
            setattr(self,field,value)
                    
t = Test({'id': 524545, 'name': 'TV', 'channels': 2})
```

`valid_attributes` is actually a `list` built from the following `Enum` and it allows me to filter out `key`s ( i.e. potential `attributes`) which are not useful for my program:

```
class fields(Enum):
    ID = "id"
    NAME = "name"
    CHANNELS = "channels"
    DESCRIPTION = "description"
    DURATION = "duration"
```

so in this example `t` will have three attributes (`id`,`name`,`channels`) which can be accessed with `t.name` or similar.

Now the problem is `typing`this attributes...infact:

```
Type of "name" is unknown
```

the problem is pretty much the same as [this](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5719#issue-366075896=)

As far as I understand declaring a `getter` or a `@property` could solve the issue, but the whole point was to have an `Enum` containing tenths of elements and just implementing them easily in the `Test` class.

I tried using `property(lambda self: str(self.key()))` right after the `setattr` declaration and explicitly converting each value in a string. But nothing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that what you actually need is a [`@dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass).

Comment: ohh nice! you mean I could replace the `Enum`...?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is either a NamedTuple or a @dataclass.

For instance, using NamedTuple:

```
class Test(NamedTuple):
    id_num: int
    name: str
    channels: int
    description: Optional[str] = None
    duration: Optional[int] = None
                    
t = Test(id_num=52545, name='TV', channels=2)
```

Note: `id` is a builtin, so usage of that as a name for a symbol is a bad idea.

Comment: Using `id` here won't shadow the built-in `id` anywhere. The documentation itself provides an example of `id` used as a field name.

Comment: `id` would shadow the builtin if you have a field with a default value that invokes `id`.

https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=d41e34c30a4c2424369929a834bcbca3

The docs provide an example where "id" is used as a field name in intialization via a factory function where this problem would not occur.

Comment: That's less a problem with the field name than it is a problem with the default.

Comment: That's not true. There's no reason that it's unreasonable to initialize a class variable to the ID of some other singleton or ID of some immutable type constant.

Comment: Then that's something to worry about when and if it happens. Nobody assigning a simple integer to use as (likely) a database key is going to care about Python object identifiers.